# Dynamic array of integers

Tags: c

I implemented a vector class in C for integers. Any feedback welcome.

header:

```
#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 1000

// Define a vector type
typedef struct 
{
  int nrOfElements;     // Current number of elements.
  int capacity; // Possible capacity.  
  int *data;    // Pointer to array elements.    
} CVectorInt;

typedef enum {VECTOR_SUCCESS, VECTOR_OUTOFBOUNDS, VECTOR_MEMORYERROR} vector_error;

vector_error CVectorInit(CVectorInt *vector);
vector_error CVectorAppend(CVectorInt *vector, int value);
vector_error CVectorGet(CVectorInt *vector, int index, int * value);
vector_error CVectorSet(CVectorInt *vector, int index, int value);
void CVectorFree(CVectorInt *vector);
```

.c:

```
#include "CVectorInt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


vector_error CVectorInit(CVectorInt *vector)
{
    int i = 0;

    vector->capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    vector->nrOfElements = 0;
    vector->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * vector->capacity);
    if(vector->data == NULL)
        return VECTOR_MEMORYERROR;

    // Initialization in C never hurts.
    for(i = 0; i<DEFAULT_CAPACITY; i++)
        vector->data[i] = 0;

    return VECTOR_SUCCESS;
}

vector_error CVectorAppend(CVectorInt *vector, int value) 
{
    int * ptr = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    // Resize vector if there is no space for more elements.
    if(vector->capacity == vector->nrOfElements)
    {
        vector->capacity *= 2;
        ptr = realloc(vector->data, vector->capacity * sizeof(int));
        if(ptr == NULL)          
        {       
            return VECTOR_MEMORYERROR;
        }
        else
        {
            vector->data = ptr; 

            // Initialize new elements to 0.
            for(i = vector->nrOfElements; i<vector->capacity; i++)
                vector->data[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    vector->data[vector->nrOfElements++] = value;

    return VECTOR_SUCCESS;


}

vector_error CVectorGet(CVectorInt *vector, int index, int * value)
{
    if(index < vector->nrOfElements && index >= 0)
    {
        // Pass value at given index.
        *value = vector->data[index];
        return VECTOR_SUCCESS;
    }else
    {
        return VECTOR_OUTOFBOUNDS;
    }
}

vector_error CVectorSet(CVectorInt *vector, int index, int value)
{
    if(index >= vector->capacity)
        return VECTOR_OUTOFBOUNDS;

    vector->data[index] = value;

    return VECTOR_SUCCESS;

}


void CVectorFree(CVectorInt *vector)
{
  free(vector->data);
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "CVectorInt.h"

int main(void) 
{
    //error handling omitted for simplicity

    CVectorInt v;
    int i = 0, temp = 0;

    CVectorInit(&v);
    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        CVectorAppend(&v, i*2);
    }

    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        CVectorGet(&v, i, &temp);
        printf("%d ", temp);
    }

    CVectorFree(&v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you handled overflow errors appropriately?

Comment: @Pimgd what kind of overflow errors are you referring to

Comment: `vector->capacity *= 2;` what happens if you go over max int here? Because if it fails with memory error in `realloc` then it's fine, but else you will underflow `nrOfElements` and start accessing negative indices.

Comment: @Pimgd I see yeah we can assume user should not add that many elements such that capacity overflows

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: @Mast I omitted there something regardless if someone answered, so if I can't changed it, so be it.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit again. If you've updated your code, feel free to ask a new question. We take answer invalidation serious here, don't do it. Please read the link I've provided in the previous comment.

Comment: @User100 I recommend you go with a follow up question, you got answers here, apply the changes, apply your own changes, as a new question, mark an answer here as accepted and ignore this one.

Comment: @Mast You should consider that sometimes the edit doesn't invalidate the answers though.

Comment: @User100 If you disagree with any decision a user made, take it to [meta.codereview.se] or find us in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `uint` for things where you cannot have negative values.

```
vector_error CVectorGet(CVectorInt *vector, int index, int * value)
{
    if(index < vector->nrOfElements && index >= 0)
```

This check, for instance, wouldn't need the comparison with 0 if you used `uint`.

In the comments I already said something about overflow. Now, you can indeed say "that's such a big amount of elements, people are not going to surpass this" and not build it in. That's okay. Be sure to add it in as a comment in the header though, because you don't want to accidentally find out that this is a problem.

Comment: Regarding the unsigned: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/30395205

Answer (score 2):

Some points:

- `CVectorSet`: what should happen if `index > vector->nrOfElements`? Should `nrOfElements=index`?
- The `vector_error` enum should be rename as `vector_status`, I think.
- `vector->capacity *= 2;` This is a geometric progression, it may grows faster then the user think. You may want to use an arithmetic progression (`vector->capacity += DEFAULT_CAPACITY;` for example).
- `vector->capacity *= 2;` You should fix a limit to the capacity.
- `if(index >= vector->capacity) return VECTOR_OUTOFBOUNDS;` Why not checking the lower bound too? (Or use unsigned int.)
- Since you're initializing the space to zero, you should use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: "Should nrOfElements=index?" no I just increase `nrOfElements`

Comment: if `nrOfElements>index` then I don't increase `nrOfElements`